# Authenticating Jupyter notebook on docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install jupyter notebook docker container on my Mac laptop. With the following options

```
docker run -dit --rm -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
```

The container starts up and I can assess it on http://[cointainer-IP]:8888 as expected.

However it takes me to an authentication screen and asks for a token. How do i get the token, which log should I look for in the docker container

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `stdout` of the container will give you a special URL that has a token for you to login with. You can either run in the foreground (without `-d`) or just checking the current container logs with `docker logs <container_id>`. There, you should see output like the following:

```
[I 16:57:05.859 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 16:57:05.871 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 16:57:05.877 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /notebooks
[I 16:57:05.877 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels 
[I 16:57:05.877 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=42685cc246e6571c0f16417327fbf4c398061125c00edea5
[I 16:57:05.877 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 16:57:05.878 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=42685cc246e6571c0f16417327fbf4c398061125c00edea5
```

Comment: The token that is attached to this output does not work for me. I keep getting "invalid token." Any ideas why this is/how to fix it?

Comment: This didn't work for me. I kept getting "invalid token" as @jblakeley . But after killing a process that was using port 8888 by `lsof -ti:8888 | xargs kill -9` I get no more annoying token messages

Comment: Make sure you aren't running jupyter on your host machine. That will interfere with the token input since both will be on port 8888. Stopping the local version of jupyter on my host and inputting the token solved the issue for me

Comment: @user3780173 this is key! I had the same issue. Wish this were listed somewhere very clearly in the docs!

Comment: @user3780173 I wish I could upvote you 10 times. I was working with PyCharm and it had its own Jupyter server running... thanks a ton!

Answer (score 6):

You can also disable the token or add a customised token with the `--NotebookApp.token=''` parameter of the `start-notebook.sh` script. Coping the token from the Terminal often causes errors and is uncomfortable.

#### Disable token

Easily as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

#### Customised Token

However, this is not recommended and you have the option to define an easy password:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token='MY_EASY_PASSWORD'
```

Comment: i successfully disabled the password using the above method in `docker run`

Comment: but i have a  doubt how can i do the same in docker-compose file??

Answer (score 2):

I have written the following code for myself to automatically open a browser and enter authentication:

```
docker exec -it <docker container name> bash -c 'jupyter notebook list' | grep http | cut -f1 -d ' ' | xargs xdg-open
```

Works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: your command returned an error for me. Simply doing `docker exec -it <docker-container-name>  bash -c 'jupyter notebook list'` was the solution for me. Thanks for your response tho!

Comment: Hi @GabrielZiegler, could you specify what error you received? And if possible what docker version of jupyter notebook you were using and/or your OS version?

Comment: Sorry, my xdg-open default is malconfigured, that is why I encountered an error executing xdg-open in an URL. The error: `which: no firefox-bin in (/opt/firefox-nightly)
Opening in existing browser session.`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following commands and copy the container ID number:

```
docker ps -a

docker logs <containerid>
```

From the log records, look for "To access the server .." like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is in my situation: the only way I could solve this (thanks to a comment by @user3780173 in the accepted answer) was to close another instance of jupyter that I had running in my host machine. Only then I could open the notebook within docker. Before that, I entered the token produced by docker but always got "invalid credentials".